# Encode XML string

Tags: xml, vbscript

I have some text which I should save in to xml file. But inside text are some XML not allowed symbols (like unicode: 0xb). How I can filter them? Is in VBScript method similar to HTMLEncode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP has a [`HTMLEncode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525347.aspx) method, but plain VBScript does not. You need to implement it yourself, for instance like this:

```vb
Function EncodeCharacter(m, p, s)
    EncodeCharacter = "&#" & Asc(m) & ";"
End Function

Function EncodeString(s)
    Set re = New RegExp
    re.Pattern = "[^a-zA-Z0-9 .:;!?/_-]"
    re.Global  = True

    EncodeString = re.Replace(s, GetRef("EncodeCharacter"))
End Function

str = ...
encoded = EncodeString(str)
```

The above code uses a regular expression with a [replacement function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974619.aspx) to substitute special characters with their corresponding numeric entity. Adjust the regular expression as you see fit, so that it covers all characters you don't want replaced.